# Terraform map transformation

Tags: terraform

I have been banging my head for a few days trying to do this. I know I have probably seen it before but google is failing me.
I have created a local from a data source.:

```
locals {
    my_new_map = [for group in data.okta_groups.aws_groups.groups: {
        id = group.id 
        name = group.name
    } if contains(local.groups_not_to_check, group.name) == false] 
}
```

the result is

```
[
  {
    id = <group1id>
    name = <group1name>
  },
  {
    id = <group2id>
    name = <group2name>
  },
  {
    ...
  },
]
```

What i need is to transform it to this:

```
[
  <group1name> = <group1id>,
  <group2name> = <group2id>,
  ...
]
```

groupnames and ids are all unique so can be used as keys

Don’t know if it is possible in my for statement or not but am willing to create a local to do it.
Any help would be awesome.

Have tried many combinations of the FOR expression but to no avail.
Maybe i am missing a function of some sort that could help or maybe i just haven't hit the correct way to output the For expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do what you want:

```
 locals { 
     my_new_map = {for group in data.okta_groups.aws_groups.groups: 
     group.name => group.id if contains(local.groups_not_to_check, group.name) == false } 
}
```

Comment: Wow I thought I had tried this. had to make a minor update to your code.  The if statement needed to inside the }.  So the result was the following

locals {
    my_new_map = {for group in data.okta_groups.aws_groups.groups: 
        group.name => group.id if contains(local.groups_not_to_check, group.name) == false }
}